# How to Send a message form One PC to Another PC

Tags: c#, winforms, communication, lan

In my application I kept a Messaging service, for that i have to send message form one PC to another PC which are connected through LAN.

example:
when a person Delete a record from the DB means, Message has to flash the Senior Authorities
"**Records Delete By Mr.XXXX**"
How to do, Any suggestions??

Comment: Are you sure you want physical inter-PC messaging as opposed to some auditing information in the database with a report on top?

Answer (score 0):

Sockets or maybe `net send msg`

[Here](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/2/10085799/how-to-send-message-via-lan.aspx), the same question (in other forum). I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Try WCF:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tomholl/archive/2008/05/17/building-a-pub-sub-message-bus-with-wcf-and-msmq.aspx